# Pandas remove only the character following a '"'

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, replace

in a pandas df i want to replace every whitespace following a '"' how can i do that?
My try on this was:

```
df['raw_data'].str.replace(r'"(\s)','')
```

However this replaces the '"' aswell. Thank you

Comment: You know what the text is that's getting eaten - always just the `"` - so add it back in the replacement.

Answer (score 2):

```
df['raw_data'].str.replace(r'"\s*','"')
```

replace every `"` with any number of spaces following it, with just a single `"`

Answer (score 1):

You can use capturing groups:

```
df['raw_data'].str.replace(r'(")(\s)', r'\1')
```

Or lookbehind:

```
df['raw_data'].str.replace(r'(?<=")(\s)', '')
```

Comment: nice demonstration of capture groups and lookbehinds (although imho probably a bit overboard for this particular problem, still great :) )

Comment: Yes I agree, your solution is much simpler ;)